# Central admin no longer available, asks to set up new farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, central-administration, server-farm

I have a development Sharepoint 2010 enterprise edition. My account has full control and SPShellAdmin credentials on the SQL database farms. Last spring I developed some custom web parts for my company. After deploying the code to production around early summer I have not logged in or touched it or the dev SQL server until yesterday to start developing some new additions. When I attempted to run the code I got an error:

> Error occurred in deployment step "Recycle IIS Application Pool". The
>   local SharePoint server is unavailable. Check that the server is connected to the SharePoint Farm

So after checking the application pool i decided to check SharePoint Central Administration where i get this message:

> Cannot browse to the SharePoint Central Administration Web Application because a SharePoint Central Administration Web Application has not been created yet. To create one, use the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard. Do you want to launch the configuration wizard now?

I click yes, enter the dev sql server name, and select my sharepoint config. Then it asks for a passphrase. The company i work for has a high turnaround with consultants so the person who created the dev server no longer works here and did not leave any documentation when he set up the server. I sent an email to his company but until i get a reply i have to assume he does not have that information or does not work there anymore.

So i found a couple options: 1st use Sharepoint management shell to reset the passphrase or 2nd create a new SharePoint farm, use the farm credentials to then reset the passphrase on the correct farm as described [Here](http://mikessharepoint.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/forgot-farm-passphrase-to-the-only-sharepoint-server-recreate-farm-walkthrough/)

First option: I launch management shell as administrator. I get the error

> "The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependancyId
>   are not registered."

I ran the command `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell` which said it is already added. I then edited the properties of management shell to be version 2, and eventually uninstalled the powershell version 3 update altogether and I still have this issue. These three are the most common causes for this error and I can't find anything else with this error. Because i am not able to run any SharePoint commands i am not able to reset the passphrase through the SharePoint Management Shell.

Second option: I created a new farm using the Central Admin wizard and gave it a passphrase "Passphrase1" since it is temporary. In the blog I am following it suggests central admin will open, but that did not happen. So i tried launching it and got the same error. So I attempt to set it up with the new temp farm, get to the passphrase portion and it says the passphrase is incorrect.

I seem to have hit two dead ends here. Does anyone have any advice on where to go from here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back up your Content DBs (if an all in one box), flatten the system and rebuild from scratch.

SharePoint environments can be quite disposable in a way - it is often far faster to rebuild a web front end than to troubleshoot an issue. Farms can also be rebuilt from backups sometimes much faster than troubleshooting issues like these.

Comment: Thanks, that is a fair point. If i go that route I'll mark this as the answer.